# How to include a nested factor in a SIMPER test in PRIMER

Tags: similarities

I'm trying to conduct a SIMPER analysis in PRIMER. I'm wanting to do the analysis using a factor that is made up of the interaction between 2 other factors, with one nested in a third.
I'm looking at the response of invertebrates after fire across time and at multiple sites. So the factor is ***timeXsite(impact)*** where site is nested in Impact and where impact is either fire or control. The simper pane in Primer allows you to select a single factor but I can't work out how to set ***timeXsite(impact)*** as one of those options as I want the simper results to take into account the nesting of site within impact.

Any ideas are welcome.
Thanks